# SSH tunnel with rsa identity without passphrase

Tags: ssh

I created key pair by command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f "C:\ssh2\id_rsa"
```

After I tried to connect to remoted server by command

```
ssh -2 -Nv -L 81:192.168.45.12:8989 proxy@host.ru -p 10022 -i "C:\ssh2\id_rsa"
```

And all finished that server required passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\ssh2\id_rsa':
```

But I created key pair without passphrase (-N ""). Why does it require passphrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Here are log which I give when I try to connect.]

I understand that connection happen, but if I click Enter button, console write me

```
debug1: No more authentification methods to try 
Permission denied (publickey, hostbased)
```

Answer (score 1):

The command issued specified "" - an empty string! - as *the* passphrase, not generation with no passphrase. (Simply hit "enter" when prompted for the passphrase and viola!)

To generate a key without *any* passphrase, do *not* specify the [optional `-N` (passphrase) option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) when creating a new key or when requesting to change the passphrase (see `-p`) ..

.. and may the foil-hat gnomes be merciful to you.

Comment: Can I change current password with command: ssh-keygen -p -P "" -f "C:\ssh2\id_rsa"???

Comment: @user3610700 Sure, see `-p -P`, from above link.

Comment: I write in console: ssh-keygen -p -P "" -f "c:\ssh2\id_rsa" and it write me back "Bad passphrase". Does it mean that passphrase is not empty string ("")???

Comment: @user3610700 Hmm, odd. It should be the same passphrase ("") unless it was already changed .. Just generate a new key pair xD

Comment: Can private key file permissions influence on passphrase? And if I write here my logs from connection, can it help you to know what's the problem?